# How to automatically update same field in different collections in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore as my database and I have collections of `users` where are stored basic information about user such as id, name, last name, email, company id.

Also I have collection of `companies` and in each company I have collection of `tasks`.
In each task I have one user assigned from collections of users (user data is replicated, so I have same data for that user as in collection `users`)

The problem is when I update user (change name or email...) from collection `users` because data is replicated that data is not changed in collection of `tasks` for that specific user.

Is there any way that using firestore when user from collection `users` is updated to automatically update it in collection of `tasks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a standard case in NoSQL databases, where we often denormalize data and need to **keep these data in sync**.

Basically you have two possible main approaches:

### #1 Update from the client

When you update the "user" document, update at the same time the other documents (i.e. "tasks") which contain the user's details. You should use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to do so: A batch of writes completes atomically and can write to multiple documents.

Something along the following lines:

```
// Get a new write batch
var batch = db.batch();

var userRef = db.collection('users').doc('...');
batch.update(userRef, {name: '....', foo: '....'});

let userTaskRef = db.collection('companies').doc('...').collection('tasks').doc('taskId1');
batch.update(userTaskRef, {name: '....'});

userTaskRef = db.collection('companies').doc('...').collection('tasks').doc('taskId2');
batch.update(userTaskRef, {name: '....'});

// ...

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then(function () {
    // ...
});
```

---

Note that you need to know which are "the other ("tasks") documents which contain the user's details": you may need to do a query to get these documents (and their `DocumentReference`s).

### #2 Update in the back-end via a Cloud Function

Write and deploy a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated) that is triggered when any "user" document is updated and which takes the value of this "user" document and update the "tasks" documents which contain the user's details.

Like for the first approach, you also need, in this case, to know which are "the other ("tasks") documents which contain the user's details.

*Following your comment ("Is there any option to reference to another table or put foreign key?")* here is a Cloud Function that will update all the ("tasks") documents that have their `DocumentReference` contained in a dedicated Array field `taskRefs` in the "user" doc. The Array members are of [data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#data_types) **Reference**.

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {

        const newValue = change.after.data();

        const name = newValue.name;
        const taskRefs = newValue.taskRefs;
        
        const promises = taskRefs.map(ref => { ref.update({ name: name, foo: "bar" }) });
        return Promise.all(promises);

    });
```

---

You would most probably set the value of this `taskRefs` field in the "user" doc **from your frontend**. Something along the following lines with the JS SDK:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection('users').doc('...').set({ 
   field1: "foo",
   field2: "bar",
   taskRefs: [   // < = This is an Array of References
       db.collection('tasks').doc('....'),
       db.collection('tasks').doc('....')] 
 });
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any option to reference to another table or put forgein key?

Comment: Yes you could maintain in the user document a list of all the References to the tasks docs. This will avoid querying for these tasks. Take care however that there are some [limits to a Firestore doc](https://firebase.google.com/doc/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields), e.g. Maximum size for a document = 1 MiB and Maximum size of a field value = 1 MiB - 89 bytes.

Comment: Could you update your answer with that third option please so we can have it all in one place

Comment: For large fanout data, this solution is not work properly. I hope firebase can support an extension to do this thing.